# Retrieve data from another sheet with its position and not its name

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to retrieve data from a specific sheet in my document, but I don't want to use the name of the sheet as reference, but its position.

Google help says this:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75943?hl=en

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

Where `Sheet1` is the name of the sheet.

Is there a way to use the sheet position instead?

E.g.:

```
=<sheetInPosition2>!A1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Use the [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) method from the Spreadsheet object of Google Apps Script

## Explanation

Google Sheets doesn't have a built-in function to get the sheet name by its position but it's possible to extended it by using Google Apps Script. The following is an example of a custom function that returns the sheet name given a valid position, otherwise return a custom error message.

```
function getSheetNameByPosition(position){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var result = '';
  try {
    return ss.getSheets()[position-1].getName();
  } catch(e) {
    throw new Error('The position value is not valid');
  }
}
```

## References

[Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Comment: I commented a line of the code as it's not necessary (you could remove it). This will improve performance.